# How to get the selected option from column filter dropdown in jquery.tablesorter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Html table in which column filter has been added for one column of the table.

Upon selecting the dropdown how can I get the selected value ?

can you suggest me if any one has any idea?

**HTML:**

```
<table id="maintable" class="tablesorter custom-popup">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filter-false">S.no</th>
            <th class="filter-false">name</th>
            <th class="filter-select" data-placeholder="Select All">Department</th>
            <th class="filter-false">Age</th>
            <th class="filter-false">Section</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         //table body
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    /*** custom css only button popup ***/
    $(".custom-popup").tablesorter({
        headers: {2: {sorter: 'name'} },
        sortList: [[1,0],[2,0],[5,0],[3,0]],
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columnSelector', 'stickyHeaders','sort2Hash', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions : 

        filter_cssFilter: '', // or []
            // if true, a filter will be added to the top of each table column;
            // disabled by using -> headers: { 1: { filter: false } } OR add class="filter-false"
            // if you set this to false, make sure you perform a search using the second method below
       filter_columnFilters: true
```

Comment: You want it as a part of a built-in event or an external event?

Comment: I want as an external event only.

Comment: Posted an answer, check if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each filter has a `.tablesorter-filter` class.

Furthermore, it has a `data-column` attribute and its value is the index of the column (0 is the value of the first column).

Therefore:

```
$('.my-custom-button').click(function(){
  var filterValue = $('.tablesorter-filter[data-column=2]').val();
});
```

Comment: Oh nice..is there any extra class added to the filtered row in the table..?

Comment: Amm... I'm not sure, I think not but you can simply check the "inspect element" tool in your browser.

Comment: I am doing table row toggling using my own js code by providing common class for some of the rows..Toggling and column filter is conflicting when both event triggered.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Please post a new question with that toggling event code

Comment: Sure.Thanks for your help.

Comment: ..posted new question .please take a look.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981428/jquery-table-column-filter-and-row-toggling-together-not-working-properly