# jquery- table column filter and row toggling together not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a table with column filter and a button "test" for toggling rows of that table
**HTML**

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.combined.js"></script>
<script src="js/widget-columnSelector.js"></script>
<script src="js/widget-sort2Hash.js"></script>

<div>
<input type="button" id="test" className="invalid" value="Hide">
<table id="testtable" class="tablesorter custom-popup">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filter-false">S.no</th>
            <th class="filter-false">name</th>
            <th class="filter-select" data-placeholder="Select All">Department</th>
            <th class="filter-false">Age</th>
            <th class="filter-false">Section</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr class="invalid">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>yyy</td>
    <td>CSE</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>A</td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>zzz</td>
    <td>ECE</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>A</td>
<tr>
<tr class="invalid">
..
    </tr>     
...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').on('click', function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('className');

        if ($(this).val() == 'Hide' ) {
            $('#testtable tr.' + name).hide();
            $(this).val('Show');
        } else{
            $('#testtable tr.' + name).show();
            $(this).val('Hide');
        }

    });

});
```

With the above JS code I can able to toggle rows which has class name "invalid".
But when I tried to add column filter in Department column, toggling is not working properly.

1.If I filter the column by selecting any option from dropdown and clicking hide button, The filtered row which has "invalid" is hiding properly..but if again i pressed show it showing all the "invalid" rows not only filtered.

2.If I filter the column by selecting any option and pressed hide,now rows are hided then if i select "select all", it is showing full table.

I dont even have any idea to solve above scenarios.
Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Maybe: Your JS code: $('#testtable tr.' + name).hide(); while in the HTML code: <table id="maintable" ...
Do you get any errors on your browser's console?

Comment: So sry..I wrongly typed here..I will edit it.

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle for this case? It should work.

Comment: @OfirBaruch ,created Fiddle. toggling working but column filter is not working..please see here https://jsfiddle.net/0jLhLebe/2/

Comment: The current code seems to work. no? Can you add the "filtering" option to the jsFiddle?

Comment: I have added..But I have no idea why it is not displaying the filter.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Added filter also..please take a look

Comment: Have you added it to the jsfiddle? Remember that you need to click "save" and afterwards you get a new URL to the jsfiddle - paste it here.

Comment: Ya..I am sry.. https://jsfiddle.net/0jLhLebe/10/